# Sitecore SXA search doesnt work

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search

I have recently installed a fresh Sitecore 8.2 update 5 including

- Power Shell 4.7.2
- SXA 1.5 rev 171010
- Sitecore SXA Showcase v1.2

Everything seems working fine except for the search function. When I typed in `About` it shows the loading icon for a split second and disappeared. Also no other search component return results. So, I configured Sitecore to use Solr 5.1.0, but it still doesn't work.

Here's the log after i typed in "About" in the search box :

> 9640 10:27:04 INFO Solr Query - ?q=(((_path:(2c1db24e0c8e49fc9569f587509c3fd9) AND searchable_b:(True)) AND sxacontent_tm:(*about*)) AND _latestversion:(True))&start=0&rows=6&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)

Here's the final log after I hit enter in the search box :

> 9640 10:27:23 INFO Solr Query - ?q=((-_path:(825b30b4b40b422e992023a1b6bda89c) *:*) AND _name:(_url))&rows=1&fq=_templatename:("Template field")&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)

Here's the Solr Query :

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "q": "(((_path:(2c1db24e0c8e49fc9569f587509c3fd9) AND searchable_b:(True)) AND sxacontent_tm:(*about*)) AND _latestversion:(True))",
      "indent": "true",
      "start": "0",
      "fq": "_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)",
      "rows": "6",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1575257349895"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}
```

I have tried indexing manager to rebuild and re-publish but still doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I assume you tried to run the Solr query via: https://localhost:8983/solr/#/sitecore_web_index/query ? Do you get any results when running the query: "\*:\*" or when running: "sxacontent_tm:(\*about\*)"?

Comment: Yes the "*:*" do return results but the "sxacontent_tm:(*about*)" doesn't . Also i have fixed the problem by re-install then after config solr i republish everthing and it's works like a charm, stll dont know why how it fixed. But thanks you for reply

Comment: Ok, I see that the index you are looking into is the default Sitecore index. Since you are looking for an sxa field, you might look into this index: `sitecore_sxa_web_index` Using Solr, you can check if the field is present in the index: https://localhost:8983/solr/#/sitecore_sxa_web_index/schema?field=sxacontent_tm